# Как проверить, что убраны все круги?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно, чтоб когда ткнул на круг он исчезал, а если он достигает 350px писалось *game over*. Но проблема в том, что если я нажал и все круги исчезли, то все равно вылазит *game over*. Как исправить?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.round', function() {
  this.remove()
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.round').animate({
    width: '350px',
    height: '350px'
  }, 6000, function() {
    $('#gameOver').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.round {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: red;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 style="display: none;" id="gameOver">Game over!</h1>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round green"></div>
<div class="round blue"></div>
<div class="round yellow"></div>
<div class="round yellow"></div>
<div class="round blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно проверить, существуют ли еще такие элементы, и если их количество больше 0, значит Game Over

```js
$(document).on('click', '.round', function() {
  this.remove()
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.round').animate({
    width: '350px',
    height: '350px'
  }, 6000, function() {
    if ($('.round').length > 0)
      $('#gameOver').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.round {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: red;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 style="display: none;" id="gameOver">Game over!</h1>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round green"></div>
<div class="round blue"></div>
<div class="round yellow"></div>
<div class="round yellow"></div>
<div class="round blue"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Уничтожение кругов никак не влияет на то, что в конце анимации будет выполнена функция с отображением надписи.

Как вариант решения, проверяйте в конце анимации наличие кругов. Есть - значит выводим надпись.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.round', function() {
    this.remove()
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.round').animate({
        width: '350px',
        height: '350px'
    },6000, function () {
      if($('.round').length)
        $('#gameOver').show();
    });
});
```

```css
    .round {
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }
    .green {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 80px;
        color: red;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="display: none;" id="gameOver">Game over!</h1>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round green"></div>
<div class="round blue"></div>
<div class="round yellow"></div>
<div class="round yellow"></div>
<div class="round blue"></div>
```

Comment: хых) на 12 секунд раньше

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!